# When applying the websocket example why does sha1sum print a different result?

Tags: linux, bash

**Background:**
I'm learning about websockets and try to implement a minimal server.

**My problem:**
According to the [official rfc documentation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) the sha1 hash for the string `"dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11"` should be `"b37a4f2cc0624f1690f64606cf385945b2bec4ea"`.
This is what [sha1-online](http://www.sha1-online.com/) prints, too.

But in bash using the tool sha1sum as suggested several times in stackoverflow, the result is different:

```
$ echo "dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11" \
    | sha1sum \
    | cut -d " " -f 1
05082898ab78f6da9c1ad2587b8012cd0cf52172
```

**What I tried:**
I thought it could be some problem of mixing binary strings with hexadecimal representations but converting forth and back using `xxd` didn't bring me closer to the correct solution.

`openssl dgst -sha1` prints the exact same result for this special input string

**My question** is, is there anything wrong with how I use the tool sha1sum or is there some kind of bug (I'm using the version GNU coreutils 8.21)?

**Edit:** In some tests I rather used a here-string but that apparently adds a newline too which I wasn't aware of

```
$ sha1sum <<< "dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11" \
    | cut -d " " -f 1
05082898ab78f6da9c1ad2587b8012cd0cf52172
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the sha1 hash for the string "`dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11`" should be "`b37a4f2cc0624f1690f64606cf385945b2bec4ea`"

The answer is *it is*!

The problem is with your `echo` which by default outputs a new-line(`\n`) character at the end of the string as you can see below,

```
echo "dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11"  | hexdump -c
0000000   d   G   h   l   I   H   N   h   b   X   B   s   Z   S   B   u
0000010   b   2   5   j   Z   Q   =   =   2   5   8   E   A   F   A   5
0000020   -   E   9   1   4   -   4   7   D   A   -   9   5   C   A   -
0000030   C   5   A   B   0   D   C   8   5   B   1   1  \n
000003d
```

Now use the `-n` flag to print without the new line character,

```
echo -n "dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11"  | hexdump -c
0000000   d   G   h   l   I   H   N   h   b   X   B   s   Z   S   B   u
0000010   b   2   5   j   Z   Q   =   =   2   5   8   E   A   F   A   5
0000020   -   E   9   1   4   -   4   7   D   A   -   9   5   C   A   -
0000030   C   5   A   B   0   D   C   8   5   B   1   1
000003c
```

So doing the same for your actual example,

```
echo -n "dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11" \
  | sha1sum  \
  | cut -d " " -f 1
b37a4f2cc0624f1690f64606cf385945b2bec4ea
```

From the man `man` page of `echo`

> -n     do not output the trailing newline

It is better to use a more portable `printf` (See [Why printf is better then echo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819)) for this,

```
printf "dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11" \
  | sha1sum  \
  | cut -d " " -f 1
b37a4f2cc0624f1690f64606cf385945b2bec4ea
```

---

Also you can get rid of any third party GNU tools like `cut`, for this and just the built-in `set` for processing output as positional parameters,

```
set -- $(printf "dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11" | sha1sum)

printf "%s\n" "$1"
b37a4f2cc0624f1690f64606cf385945b2bec4ea
```

Comment: the echo was just for simplification but reading your answer I reread all of my code and saw that everytime a newline was inserted somehow. Thanks a lot for that clarification; I'll edit my question for others thinking "echo can't be the issue"

Comment: @Hachi: Am not sure I understand what you mean `echo` is _the_ issue for you.